# How to remove all element Except first element and Second element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML

```
<div class="geo_select">
      <h3>header 3</h3>
      <div class="row form-group">
         default content
      </div>
      <div class="row form-group">
         //Dynamic content 1 here
      </div>
     <div class="row form-group">
         //Dynamic content 2 here
      </div>

    </div>
```

in Above HTML code i want to remove all element except `<h3>` and default content`<div>` inside the `<div class='geo_select'>` in jquery.. How to remove all element except first 2 element in jquery? in my above scenario?

Comment: Give all the dynamic content an additional class and remove all div element with that class.Won't that be easier ?

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to do that in jQuery

```
// use this, if there are different types of elements as child 
$('.geo_select > div:nth-of-type(n+3)').remove()

// use any of these if childs are same
$('.geo_select > div:nth-child(n+3)').remove()
$('.geo_select > div:gt(2)').remove()

// this is jQuery way which reduce the set into the range 
$('.geo_select > div').slice(2).remove()
```

---

Or with css, simply hide it.

```
.geo_select > div:nth-of-type(n+3){
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use CSS if you want.

```
.geo_select > div:not(:first-of-type) {
    display:none;
}
```